# Can't enter test user email for in-app purchase sandbox

Tags: iphone, app-store

I've created my iTunes Connect in-app test user and implemented all my in-app purchase code.  I clicked on the home button -> settings -> appstore -> signout button.  I launch my app through xcode.  When it goes to perform a purchase transaction it continues to bring up my real itunes connect user info prompting me for the password.  Even though it shows me as signed out in the settings appstore screen it never prompts me to enter my test user's email address when I'm testing in-app purchases.

Anyone have any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

Might try rebooting your device.  If you go into the AppStore.app, Featured Tab, and scroll all the way to the bottom where it should show your login name, are you still signed in?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you did not install your development version over distribution version.

My case:
I’ve downloaded my application from Apple AppStore – distribution version. Later, started  debug session over installed application and got the same situation as described the question author. No sandbox environment for in-app purchase.

- Solution:
  Just uninstall the application and start debug/test your application again – xcode will install development version to your device.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a new way to log in and log out test users. Under

```
Settings -> iTunes & App Store
```

You can manage your current sandbox user. If you log out the sandbox user there you will be asked to give the email address for your user when you try buying inside your app.